# Menu text disappears when you hover over a menu that is in a kendo ui grid toolbar in

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In **Kendo UI** When you hover over a **menu** in a **grid toolbar**, the menu text disappears. I wondered whether this was a kendo ui bug or whether I have done something wrong? I’m using the metro theme.

Here's a screen shot of the problem:
[image]

Here's the code that recreates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='grid'></div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
        <div>
            <ul id='menu'>
                <li><span>Options</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Custom Option</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: []
                }),
                columns: [{
                    field: "FIELD1",
                    title: "Field 1"
                }]
            }).data("kendoGrid");

            $("#menu").kendoMenu();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the color on:hover may be its #fff

Comment: did you check with firebug whether an `opacity:0` is applied to css?

Comment: Which browser, OS and Kendo UI version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Kendo bug. You'll find it happens with the 2013.3.1114 version of the CSS but the problem is fixed in the 2013.3.1315 release.